# Less mixin to create responsive floating classes

Tags: html, css, less

I need to create a mixin in LESS for responsive floating (to mimic the floats in bootstrap 4) for a project i'm working on. I'm a LESS newbie so i'm kind of lost in the logic. I know i have to create a recursive loop with

```
.make-floats(@array, @index: 1) when (@index <= length(@array)){

}
```

where `@array` has all the breakpoints inside, but i can't figure out how to implement it in a way that i can use classes like `float-left-xs`on my markup. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you explain what items does `@array` contain? And what is expectes css output?

Comment: it should have the breakpoints of bootstrap 3 and the expected output is like i mentioned in the question, responsive floating classes like "float-left-xs" "float-right-sm"